# Cloudera quick start unresponsive script

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am having the following error while accessing Hue in Cloudera quick start. I have checked the connectivity and looks fine. I am hoping if anyone can direct me on how to resolve as I am a beginner to Hadoop and stacked with this issue? I appreciate any help.
[image]

Comment: When I click continue it will take so long and bring another warning: Unresponsive script. .....js.33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickstart VM requires 6-8 GB of RAM to work well. Otherwise, your memory is probably swapping and causing it to be unresponsive

Comment: thanks for the help. I did increase the memory and now working fine.

Comment: I am trying to use Pig editor and open from the drop-down menu under Query. I say your "This is the old Pig Editor, it is recommended to instead use the new Editor". How do I install the new version?

Comment: I don't use Pig in Hue, but maybe it wants you to use a Notebook

Comment: Thanks, Cricket_007, the issue gets resolved when I re-install with the latest version.